# shortcuts to put a window at a particular location on screen?

Tags: kubuntu, shortcut-keys, kde, plasma

This is really a KDE/Plasma question -- if there is a better place to ask it, please point that out to me.

Running Kubuntu 16.04.1. Having a very wide (21:9) monitor is nice, but one thing that was nice about two 24 inch monitors was that telling a window to go "full screen" would occupy exactly half of my viewing area.

I'm trying to emulate that without having to futz around with the mouse for half an hour at a time: hit a function key, and have the current (konsole) window get a particular geometry (so: location and size), and hopefully also get rid of the window manager decoration so it occupies the full vertical space of the screen.

Any suggestions, or, better yet, pointers to relevant documentation?

Comment: Do you want to tile the windows like one window on the top left or one window on the top right or say one window that occupies the complete the whole bottom half of your screen?

Answer (score 1):

Without going into too many details, you want `xdotool` , which is installable via `sudo apt-get install getactivewindow`.

Basic command that you'd want to run is something like this:

```
xdotool getactivewindow  windowmove X Y  windowsize Width Height
```

So actual command to move your active window would be something like this:

```
xdotool getactivewindow  windowmove 0 0  windowsize 250 250
```

You can bind this to keyboard shortcut for convenience , too

Answer (score 1):

There's this awesome program on [GitHub](https://github.com/ssokolow/quicktile) called `Quicktile`. It's basically a python script but works wonder. To install it first install the dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install python python-gtk2 python-xlib python-dbus python-wnck
```

Then:

1. Download it and extract `quicktile.py` to wherever you want to keep it.
2. Set `quicktile.py` to be executable if it isn't already.
3. Run `quicktile.py` once to generate your configuration file.
4. Edit`~/.config/quicktile.cfg` to customize your keybinds.
5. Set your desktop to run `quicktile.py --daemonize` on boot.

There's also a [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZF76DELEpjM) video on the software.